# OneDrive: How to re-sync files that were offline for weeks?

Tags: sync, onedrive

I had a working OneDrive installation (corporate Office account) until I had a problem in the whole Office installation and can't log into any Office application anymore, so my files stopped being synced.

Now I got a new PC with a new working Office installation. Should I let OneDrive download all files and then copy and replace all files from the old PC, or copy the files from the old PC to a new empty folder in the new PC, point OneDrive to that folder and let OneDrive analyze those files and merge both versions?

The old PC local versions should be the latest ones, but there may be cases where the online files are the valid ones as:

- it looks to me like Word and Excel can open online files directly even if OneDrive is not running
- I may have modified a few files in the Office Web version
- other users may have modified my online shared files